# How to Remove Host from POST string using Java HttpURLConnection class?

Tags: java, http, post, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a POST request from Java but receive an error 502 from the server. Digging further it appears to be because Java includes the full https://host/path in the request whereas the server expects only the path.

Basically it sends:

> POST **https://www.dummy.com**/oauth/auth/ HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_45
>
> Host: www.dummy.com
>
> Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>
> Connection: keep-alive

instead of

> POST /oauth/auth/ HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_45
>
> Host: www.dummy.com
>
> Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>
> Connection: keep-alive

My code is as follow

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.dummy.com/oauth/auth/");
HttpURLConnection sock = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
sock.setDoOutput(true);                    
sock.setRequestMethod("POST");
...
```

Does anybody know how to remove the host and keep only the path?

Thanks!